# Bootstrap popover doesn't work inside a table

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I am trying to use bootstrap popup for dynamically generated table. In the table there is a column name `users` and it has number of users for each item.

Eg: table structure

```
item name | adress | users 
bla..blaa | bla..  |   4
```

Now I need to display a popup with user information when click on `4`.

User column HTML is something like this :

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' data-rel='popover' title='' data-content='Heads up! This alert needs your attention, but its not super important.' class='badge badge-inverse popup'>4</a>
```

This is how I tried it in query:

```
$('#view_table').find('[data-rel=popover]').popover({html:true});
```

But When I click on `4` under user column its not trigger the pupover. Mean time I checked the same HTML outside the table and I can get it to work.

Any idea to it doesn't work inside table.

Hope somebody may help me out.

Comment: If that is the markup you're using, it's invalid, since you have two title attributes.

Comment: Oh.. My mistake and corrected. But still it doesn't work

Comment: I tried in table and its working. can you update your table html here, [http://jsfiddle.net/f67pzxr0/](http://jsfiddle.net/f67pzxr0/) .

Comment: @tejashsoni111, my table is generating dynamically using jquery datatable.

Comment: Is this a even  event delegation issue?

Comment: Show some more code. Best would be an URL with working code e.g. on jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing your

```
$('#view_table').find('[data-rel=popover]').popover({html:true});
```

code after, binding the Table's HTML to the DOM, or before hand.

Try writing the above code, after the Table has been added to the DOM

Comment: I just checked it going with your answer. But still it doesn't work for me

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap 3, maybe they require you to have a `data-toggle="popover"` attribute, instead of the `data-rel` one

Comment: No.. still not. I am using bootstrap 3